Am I incorrectly interpreting axiom I, 3 of Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry?
Context
Hilbert's third axiom of incidence is:

There exist at least two points on a line. There exist at least three points that do not lie on the same line.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms)
This axiom is used to prove Theorem 3 in Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry:

THEOREM 3. For two points A and C there always exists at least one point D on the line AC that lies between A and C.

(1971 Open Court English translation)
The first statement of the proof is this:

PROOF. By Axiom I, 3 there exists a point E outside the line AC, ...


I interpreted the axiom as meaning "at least one set of three non-collinear points is guaranteed to exist", but the proof seems to require an axiom along the lines of "for every pair of distinct points A and B, there exists a third point not contained by the line AB".
Is my interpretation incorrect, or is the axiom insufficient?

Well, if all points were on the line $AB$ it would not be true that there were three points not on the same line.

Claim: For every pair of points $A, B$ there exists a point $C$ not on $AB$.
Proof:

Suppose there does not exist any such point $C$. Then all points lie on $AB$. Then there is no set of three points that do not lie in the same line.

This contradicts the third incidence axiom, so by contradiction we can assume that a point $C$ exists not on the line $AB$.


